# Discontinuous function by epsilon delta

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

How do I prove that the function $ \frac{x ^ 2 y} {| x ^ 3 | + y ^ 2} $ is not continuous on $ \{0,0\} $ using epsilon-delta?

I have tried it using sequences that have $ \{0,0 \} $, but I would like an idea to test it by epsilon-delta, since it seems that the solution is complicated by that means

Comment: How are you defining the function at the origin?

Comment: As Matthew alluded to, isn't this already discontinuous at $(0,0)$ since the function (as written) is undefined there?

Comment: and if the statement says that $f(0,0) = (0,0)$?

Comment: Luis, you should have asked about $f(0,0) = 0.$ Given values for $x,y,$ not both zero, the fraction is a single real number, not two.

Answer (score 3):

$ \frac{x ^ 2 y} {| x ^ 3 | + y ^ 2} $  is what you typed in.

Note $$  0 \leq \left( |y| -|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}  \right)^2 = y^2 - 2 |y| |x|^{\frac{3}{2}}  + |x|^3  $$

so
$$    2 |y| |x|^{\frac{3}{2}} \leq y^2 + |x|^3 $$
and
$$ \frac{ 2 |y| |x|^{\frac{3}{2}}  }{ |x|^3 + y^2 }   \leq 1   $$
as long as $x,y$ are not both zero.
Thus
$$ \frac{ 2 |y| x^2  }{ |x|^3 + y^2 }   \leq \sqrt{|x|}   $$
This means that assigning the value $0$ as the value of the function at $(0,0)$ creates a continuous function.